XGBoost: how to get tree predictions for num_parallel_tree > 1
It is explained in the XGBoost documentation that setting n_estimators == 1, num_parallel_tree > 1 (including also bootstrapping and random sampling at node level) yields the same structure as a Random Forest. Is it then possible to get access to the independent predictions of each tree?
